# How to Maintain fullscreen mode even if i refresh the page in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a requirement in my project where user should view the content in Fullscreen only.
i have handled redirection to other page if user exits Fullscreen, but the requirement is when the user refreshes the page, it should not redirect to other page and should maintain fullscreen mode and reload.

if fullscreen exits on refresh i tried to push back to fullscreen mode but not worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.